# How to ensure all JS files are loaded before executing a task when including JS files with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a js file with following code which is included in the head section of all my html pages.

```
myApp.jsLoad = (function () {

    var obj_1 = {
        getScript: jQuery.getScript,

        // Load multiple js files
        getMultipleScripts: function( filesArray, callback ) {
            var // reference declaration & localization
            length = filesArray.length,
            handler = function() { counter++; },
            deferreds = [],
            counter = 0,
            idx = 0;

            for ( ; idx < length; idx++ ) {
                deferreds.push(
                    obj_1.getScript( filesArray[ idx ], handler )
                );
            }

            jQuery.when.apply( null, deferreds ).then(function() {
                callback && callback();
            });
        } ,
        //-----End-----getMultipleScripts----------------



        // Checks if js file is being included for the first time
        // namesp: use a sub-namespace of myApp
        // jsFile: use the full filepath 
        isFirstLoad: function(namesp, jsFilepath) {

            // namesp.firstLoad will be undefined if file hasn't been included before
            var isFirst = namesp.firstLoad === undefined; 

            namesp.firstLoad = false;

            return isFirst;
        } ,
        // ----End-----------isFirstLoad----------------


        // Load js files that have not been loaded before
        // fileList is an object of namespace and filepath
        loadNewScripts:  function(fileList) {

            // RSVP.Promise uses RSVP Promise library
            return new RSVP.Promise(function(fulfill, reject) {
                var filesToLoad = [];
                $.each(fileList, function(index, el) {

                    if (!obj_1.isFirstLoad(el.nameSp, el.jsfile) ) {
                        // if file already included before
                    } else {
                        // This js file hasn't been loaded into page yet
                        // so push into filesToLoad array so we can load them altogether at once 
                        filesToLoad.push(el.jsfile);
                    }
                }); 

                obj_1.getMultipleScripts(filesToLoad, function() {
                    //Do something after all scripts have loaded
                    fulfill('JS files loaded');                 
                });

            }) // RSVP.Promise

        } ,
        //-----End------- loadNewScripts---------------------



    }; // obj_1 
    //-----End------obj_1-------------------

    return obj_1;

}());
```

The part of the above js file that is of concern here is `loadNewScripts`.
Basically what `loadNewScripts` does is that when you pass an object consisting of namespaces and filepath as an argument to it, it loads those js files if they are NOT already loaded.

This is useful because in my project I have many js files and some js files are dependent on other js files. So instead of including `<script type="text/javascript" src="somefile.js"></script>` for each js files required by a html page, I can just include one js file in my html page, and that js file will load the js files that it needs, and those loaded js files can load additional js they needed and so on.

To demonstrate, assume I have three js files: file1.js, file2.js and file3.js . Only file1.js is included in my html page initially.

In file1.js, `myApp.jsLoad.loadNewScripts` loads file2.js before executing funMath():

```
 myApp = myApp || {};
(function () {
    myApp.f2 = myApp.f2 || {};
    var fileList = [
        {
            nameSp: myApp.f2 ,
            jsfile: 'file2.js'
        }
    ];

    myApp.jsLoad.loadNewScripts(fileList)
    .then(function(loadStatus) { 
        funMath();
    })

    var funMath = function() {
        var a = myApp.f2.getNum();
        alert(a);
    }
}());
```

In file2.js, `myApp.jsLoad.loadNewScripts` loads file3.js:

```
myApp = myApp || {};
(function () {
    myApp.f3 = myApp.f3 || {};
    var fileList = [
        {
            nameSp: myApp.f3 ,
            jsfile: 'file3.js'
        }
    ];

    myApp.jsLoad.loadNewScripts(fileList)
    .then(function(loadStatus) { 
       myApp.f2 = obj;
    })

    var obj = {
        getNum: function() {
             return myApp.f3.getRand();
        }
    };
}());
```

Code in file3.js:

```
 myApp = myApp || {}

 myApp.f3 = (function () {

    var obj = {
        getRand: function() {
             return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10); 
        }
    };
    return obj
}());
```

Now in file1.js, funMath() waits until file2.js to be loaded before it executes, but how will it know whether file3.js is loaded?

file1.js is dependent on file2.js which in turn is dependent on file3.js which means file1.js is dependent on both file2.js and file3.js. How do you ensure both file2.js and file3.js is loaded before funMath() in file1.js is executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an event `load` that is triggered once your `<script src="...">` has been loaded(and since JS is single-threaded it also means it has been executed as well)

```js
var body = document.body;
var scriptEl = document.createElement('script');
scriptEl.src = 'https://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js';
scriptEl.addEventListener('load', function() {
   console.log('Underscore version is ' + _.VERSION);
});
body.appendChild(scriptEl);
```

NB Once it is not about about learning JS but real-product-task you better take a look into world of loaders and bundlers. Say requireJS or webpack(they are from different worlds but should be similar in scope of your current needs).

Yes, webpack in the first way creates single bundle but you can tune it up to split whole codebase into chunks that are loaded dynamically once you need them.